# How can I test one class at a time?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm writing a library.

I have an abstract class and multiple implementations.

```java
public abstract class MyAbstract {
}

public class MyConcrete1 extends MyAbstract {
}

public class MyConcrete2 extends MyAbstract {
}
```

Now in my unit testing, I prepared classes like this.

```java
public abstract class MyAbstractTest<T extends MyAbstract> {
    // actual test cases are here
}

public class MyConcrete1Test extends MyAbstractTest<MyConcrete1> {
}

public class MyConcrete2Test extends MyAbstractTest<MyConcrete2> {
}
```

When I run tests, those two tests classes seem run concurrently. It's not convenient to analyze.

```
log for 1...
log for 1...
log for 2...
log for 1...
log for 2...
log for 2...
```

What user properties can control this behavior with Maven and TestNG?

I tried with `-DthreadCount=1` and had no luck.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No it's not an XY problem. I wrote `I tried... no luck` just for protect myself from guys like you would say `so what have you tried so far?`

Comment: But *why* do you want to do this?  I can think of no legitimate reason why it should matter if the tests run concurrently.  If the classes under test share some static data or something, then *that* is the problem that you need to solve.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede need to analyze log? see that log?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Are you still stick to gosh-darned XY shit? Or you don't have any productive answer?

Comment: Your refusal to explain why you're trying to do this only deepens my suspicion that it's an XY problem.  And your responses suggest that you don't even understand what an XY problem is, so your stubbornness is doubly bizarre.

Comment: `-DthreadCount=1` should work. I recommend you run your maven build with debug logging enabled (`-X`) and see if your parameters were indeed used by maven.